# Can I access to this Screen if I use Google's Calendar API?

Tags: android, google-api, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to save events from my app in the Google's calendar. Now, I'm using an intent to launch this preview screen (with the fields already filled in) in case the user wants to modify any field. I want to use the Google's calendar API, I have read the documentation and I have not found the way that this screen appears. Can someone give me a hand? Thank you.[image: Google's Calendar]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Google Calendar API is a rest api.  It returns data in raw json format.   It is up to the developer to format the data and display it as they would like.

> I have read the documentation and I have not found the way that this screen appears.

The Google Calendar does not have access to any screens it only has access to data.   You will have to create your own screens and extract the data from the Api.

Most of the data in that screen can be found in the event methods found in this section of the documentation [events overview](https://developers.google.com/calendar/v3/reference/events)

Comment: remember to accept the answer if it helped you.  You will also increase your reputation by accepting anwser.